# Creating an API for a Joomla extension

Tags: joomla-api, restful-api

I need to create an API so an external client can perform actions on my custom extensions database table.

What would be the right approach?

1. Should I use https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/ for this? How?! I did not find any examples.
2. Put the API in a separate directory (for example /api/) and include the Joomla framework into my php?
3. Or create a MVC extension, for example com_myapi?
4. Should I use REST or any other method?
5. Would com_api be a good start? (https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api)
   Did not find any documentation however…

The external client should be able to:

PUT - Modify an existing object on the server
POST - Create a new object on the server
DELETE - Remove an object on the server

I should then return a response (ok, or a specific error). JSON?

OR…. Am I overlooking some obvious other great solution?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few options, but I use the jBackend extension.

Some positives of jBackend.

- Nice clean JSON
- Comes with good boilerplate code to get started
- Manages API keys API endpoint code transmits and receives data
- Basically exposes many common CMS functions as API endpoints
- Has a normal looking Joomla admin UI for managing API keys
- Documentation is good
- Code is well structured and easy to read

We've been using it for a while so Joomla can be a Backend for mobile Apps.  I did a talk about this at J&Beyond last week, which you can find at http://jandbeyond.org/programme.html?view=session&id=45&return=L3Byb2dyYW1tZS5odG1s

More details about jBackend are at http://www.selfget.com/products/jbackend.html .  I think there is also a RedComponent extension that does a similar thing.

Whilst at J&Beyond, I attended Chris Davenport's talk on Joomla 3.6 and Beyond, which had some great details on Joomla's API features that may arrive in 3.6 - http://jandbeyond.org/programme.html?view=session&id=74&return=L3Byb2dyYW1tZS5odG1s

Comment: I just watched the video of jBackend, and it looks very promising. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, they/you got me convinced just bought the extension ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you need clean REST urls like :
[GET] api/articles/1

You can have a look to my project : https://github.com/pvullioud/japi

or if you don't wont to use plugins, you have a more simple exemple here
https://github.com/pvullioud/joomla-slimframework

Comment: Both GitHub links are dead.

Comment: I guess link changed to this one https://github.com/RemcoJanssen/japi

Comment: Last commit in 2015. Dead.

Answer (score 1):

If a ready-made made extension is acceptable, then my suggestion is [Headless](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_content_management_system) Joomla and [the Virtuemart plugin from codingmall](https://codingmall.com/products-mainmenu-8/201-headless-joomla-a-virtuemart-json-output). It gives you detailed info for any Joomla view using simple REST calls like this:

```
https://www.example.com/?cmjspkjson_opt=10
```

Output:

```
{
    "item": {
        "id": "1",
        "asset_id": "61",
        "title": "Getting Started",
        "alias": "getting-started",
        "introtext": "It's easy",
        "fulltext": "",
        "state": "1",
        "catid": "2",
        "created": "2019-08-29 14:35:43",
        "created_by": "581",
        ...
    },
    "pageclass_sfx": ""
}
```

A complex call example:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&id=3&cmjspkjson_opt=10&reqobj[]=category.children
```

This will only return the required part instead of the full json output.

To save the number of requests, you may have more than one reqobj parameter.

Disclaimer: I provide technical assistance to CodingMall.com.

Comment: Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour] to earn your first badge.  If you have any affiliation with codingmall, it is required that you declare this.

Comment: Many thanks @mickmackusa